# How do I install the pdo_mysql driver on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.1?

Tags: mysql, redhat, drivers, pdo

I have a RHEL box running PHP 5.3.3, which was installed using the binary packages provided by `yum`.  I have installed the php-pdo package:

```
# yum info php-pdo
Loaded plugins: product-id, rhnplugin, subscription-manager
Updating Red Hat repositories.
Installed Packages
Name        : php-pdo
Arch        : x86_64
Version     : 5.3.3
Release     : 3.el6_1.3
Size        : 168 k
Repo        : installed
From repo   : rhel-x86_64-server-6
Summary     : A database access abstraction module for PHP applications
URL         : http://www.php.net/
License     : PHP
Description : The php-pdo package contains a dynamic shared object that will add
            : a database access abstraction layer to PHP.  This module provides
            : a common interface for accessing MySQL, PostgreSQL or other
            : databases.
```

It appears to be working correctly for SQLite databases, but not MySQL.  There's no file including pdo_mysql.so in /etc/php.d, and there is no copy of pdo_mysql.so in /usr/lib64/php/modules.

I'm pretty sure I just need the driver file and a line in the PHP configuration.  A `yum search pdo mysql` didn't turn up any useful packages, and Google has failed me.  If I were on Ubuntu or Debian, I'd `apt-get install php5-mysql` and be done with it.

So ... where in Red Hat land do I get a copy of pdo_mysql.so, and install it properly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want to install the `php-mysql` package:

```
Name       : php-mysql
Arch       : x86_64
Version    : 5.3.6
Release    : 1.w5
Size       : 210 k
Repo       : installed
Summary    : A module for PHP applications that use MySQL databases.
URL        : http://www.php.net/
License    : PHP
Description: The php-mysql package contains a dynamic shared object that will add MySQL database support to PHP. MySQL is an
           : object-relational database management system. PHP is an HTML-embeddable scripting language. If you need MySQL
           : support for PHP applications, you will need to install this package and the php package.
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! Installing that and restarting Apache got the PDO driver properly in place.

Answer (score 4):

To update this answer for lost souls in 2020, with a RHEL 8 fresh install loaded with PHP 7.2, in order for the PDO driver for mysql to show up in the phpinfo() page, two packages must be installed:
`yum -y install php-pdo php-mysqlnd`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you very much to Karl.
I was having problem to install pdo-mysql, and tried all many things, but then your suggestion to install following fixed it for me

yum install php-ZendFramework-Db-Adapter-Pdo-Mysql.noarch

My system is a Centos6.7 and I have php5.6.
another version of php was showing that pdo-mysql is installed. But phpinfo() was not showing it. When i tried yum install pdo-mysql. it was saying package is not available.
Anyway, above zend package fixed it for me.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This sounds like a thank-you "comment" ... not an answer ...

Answer (score -1):

After

```
    # yum install pdo-mysql
```

Try

```
    # yum install php-ZendFramework-Db-Adapter-Pdo-Mysql.noarch
```

Comment: How does this help ???